# Split line by spaces, but preserve strings within backticks

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, lexical-analysis

I have the following formatted data:

```
testing 25 `this is a test`
hello `world hello world`
log "log1" "log2" `third log`
```

I am currently using a combination of regex and shlex, but I'm having problems, as shown above

```py
import re, shlex

def tokenize(line):
    graveKeyPattern = re.compile(r'^ *(.*) (`.*`) *')
    if '`' in line:
        tokens = re.split(graveKeyPattern, line)
        tokens = tokens[1:3]
    else:
        tokens = shlex.split(line)
    #end if/else
    print(tokens)
    return tokens
#end tokenize

lines = []
lines.append('testing 25 `this is a test`')
lines.append('hello `world hello world`')
lines.append('log "log1" "log2" `third log`')
lines.append('testing2 "testing2 in quotes" 5')

for line in lines:
    tokenize(line)
```

This is the output I get:

```
['testing 25', '`this is a test`']
['hello', '`world hello world`']
['log "log1" "log2"', '`third log`']
['testing2', 'testing2', 'in', 'quotes', '5']
```

This is the output I need:

```
['testing', '25', '`this is a test`']
['hello', '`world hello world`']
['log', 'log1', 'log2', '`third log`']
['testing2', 'testing2 in quotes', '5']
```

Comment: Try ``["{}{}{}{}".format(x.group(1),x.group(2),x.group(3),x.group(4)) for x in re.finditer(r'''`([^`]*)`|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|(\S+)''', line)]`` or ``["{}{}{}{}".format(a,b,c,d) for a,b,c,d in re.findall(r'''`([^`]*)`|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|(\S+)''', line)]``

Comment: Ah, ``"`([^`]*)`"`` must actually be ``(`[^`]*`)`` as the backticks should be inside.

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes easier to match what you want rather than split what you don't.

This works on your tests by matching either things between backticks or non-space/quotes:

```
lines = []
lines.append('testing 25 `this is a test`')
lines.append('`world hello world` hello ')
lines.append('log "log1" "log2" `third log` log3')

import re
[re.findall(r'((?:`.*?`)|[^\"\s]+)', s) for s in lines]
```

**results**

```
[['testing', '25', '`this is a test`'],
 ['`world hello world`', 'hello'],
 ['log', 'log1', 'log2', '`third log`', 'log3']]
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! Could you walk me through what everything means though? I don't really understand regex.

Comment: @wolfy there are two main things separated by `|` which indicates one or the other:`` `.*?`  `` matches backticks and anything in-between ,  `[^\"\s]+` is one or more things that isn't a whitespace (`\s`) or a quote marks. The `^` denotes `not` inside `[..]`. Everything is inside `(..)` indicating a capture group but the parenthesis starting with `?:` indicate a non-catpure group because we don't want to capture it twice.